# Is "who's your daddy?" a command in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, command

I was randomly typing out cheesy lines on the terminal when, to my surprise, when I wrote "who's your daddy?" it actually opened some sort of interpreter. Why did this happen? When I tried to use man with this as:

```
man who's your daddy
```

I was sent to the same interpreter sort of thing. Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: When you say ‘*some sort of interpreter*’, do you mean a secondary prompt, perhaps with a `>` to the left? That's because there's a single quote in there (`'`) without a closing quote, so your shell is expecting you to enter the rest of the string. As for whether it's a command: No, since it's not syntactically complete. If you add a quote, it *will* be a command to open a certain man page (that probably doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

By typing `'` on a command line interface you opened a string which you did not close. For the interpreter (maybe bash or some other shell) you are still typing the string until another `'` follows. In some shells this is indicated by lines starting with `>` on the left.

```
$ echo this 'is
> a
> test'
```

Which produces the output:

```
this is
a
test
```

Whereas `this` is the first parameter to `echo` and the rest (including the line breaks) is the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you typed return, you did not enter some sort of interpreter, but the command line waits for you to finish your command by typing the closing single quote `'`.

Try to see what happens when you type:

```
man who's your daddy'
```